# How to create activity with text view, a button and a toast?

Tags: android-studio

I am basic. in android studio, I want to start a basic project.

I want to type "any word" in a plain text view.
Only whenever I click on a button ,Just we can see  that word as a TOAST.
this case I need : a plan text view, a button , and a toast.
How should i do this?

**Thanks for the replies.**

Comment: Please, what do you mean by _I want to type a WORD in a button shaped_ ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your xml file you need to set an id for both textviews and button
2. In your activity:

   //get the button
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but); 
   txt1= (text1) findViewById(R.id.text1); 
   txt2 = (text2) findViewById(R.id.text2); 
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           txt2.setText(txt1);
       }

Answer (score 0):

Your XML code should look like so. Note the id's of the EditText and the TextView which are crucial for extracting your strings and setting them respectively.

Also note the 'onClick' function on your button which is necessary to call upon the method in your MainActivity (Java Class) with the same name.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enterText"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="changeText"
    android:text="Show Now"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now for your MainActivity (Java) Class method:

```
public void changeText(View view){
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.enterText);
    String res = editText.getText().toString();

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.newText);
    textView.setText(res);
}
```

Again take note of the declaration of the EditText object using your 'id', "enterText" and "newText" respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're trying to say.